# Which certificate to use with Aspose for digital signatures

Tags: x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate2, aspose.pdf

I am busy with a document signing api, which will apply digital signatures to pdf documents. The digital signature must be verifiable by pdf readers(Adobe, acrobat, web browsers, etc).
Which certificate should I get? Code sign, document sign,EV etc?

I tried using windows self cert generated certificates, and worked for a while on a local app. But now moving the api to the server, the signature is not verifiable.

Comment: The information about the supported signatures can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/digitally-sign-pdf-file/) of the API. However, if you are facing some issues or need some enhancements, we request you create a post in our dedicated [Support Forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where we will assist you accordingly as it is the recommended place for such discussions. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.